# What experiment was used to measure drift velocity?

Tags: electric-fields, electric-current

I was learning about drift velocity and was wondering how scientists know that it is so slow.

Is there a famous experiment or paper that anyone is aware of that shows the techniques scientists used to measure drift velocity in a circuit?

Comment: it is a  student lab project for ions,   http://www.schoolphysics.co.uk/age16-19/Electricity%20and%20magnetism/Current%20electricity/text/Free_electron_motion/index.html  . Otherwise it is calculated  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drift_velocity#Experimental_measure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "famous experiment". But [Hall effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect) measurements were essential for the determination of electron (hole) concentration and thus drift velocity in conductors. The drift velocity $v$ of electrons in a conductor with electron concentration $n$ can be determined from the measured current $I$ and cross section $A$: $$I=A·n·e·v \tag 1$$ The electron concentration can be determined by a Hall effect measurement yielding the Hall coefficient $$R_H=-\frac {1}{e·n} \tag 2$$ Thus from eqs. (1) and (2) the drift velocity $v$ is obtained.